# Programmatically checkout a previous checked in file version

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfs-sdk

I want to checkout a previous version of a checked in file in TFS. I can easily get a list of changesets ID's for the specific file but cant work out how to checkout a previous version.

My code as it stands:

```
var workspaceInfo = Workstation.Current.GetLocalWorkspaceInfo(tfsItem.QaVssLocation);

var server = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(workspaceInfo.ServerUri);

var workSpace = workspaceInfo.GetWorkspace(server);

workSpace.Get();

workSpace.PendEdit(tfsItemLocation);
```

What is the correct method for achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else wishing to get an Item object for a specfied version of an item in TFS, the following works:

```
Item versionedItem = versionControlServer.GetItem(itemIDs[0], versionNo);
```

The array 'itemIDs' contains the ID of the item, then the specific version number is supplied. This will give you the item in the previously defined version state.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using workspace.Get(), why cant you make use of the other overloads of the Get() method. You can see the different overloads here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.workspace.get(v=vs.110).aspx